# For specialized code, use custom interfaces and types or available generic ones?

Tags: object-oriented-design

I will use Java as example, but the question pops up in my mind with any language / framework / stack / pattern / ...
For instance in python, should I just use a dict(), or should I subclass it to make my intentions clear? or is that violating duck-typing principal of python? or ...

Imagine a simple *Echo Server* running on port X. The *Server* consists of:

- `Server` accepts clients, and hands them to client handlers.
- `ClientHandler`, who handle connected clients (doh!)

Main server has a list of registered client handlers, and passes the received request to client handlers in this list, so they can handle or ignore it (not a good design but it's simple). We may now have a `ClientHandler` who echoes back the received text capitalized, one that only echoes half of it, one that ...
Now consider these two versions:

```
interface GenericServer {
    void start();
    void stop();
    // ... other server related stuff, such as set backlog.

    void registerHandler(java.util.Observer o); 
}
```

It looks like duck-typing to me, but in Java! It's okay to pass in any object of type java.util.Observer as handler. As far as `GenericServer` is concerned, it should be able to observe.
We could also do:

```
interface SpecializedServer {
    // Marker interface to make everything more clear.
    interface ClientHandler extends java.util.Observer { }

    void start();
    void stop();
    // ... other server related stuff, such as set backlog.

    void registerHandler(ClientHandler ch); 
}
```

Now it uses a *Marker Interface* to say **Attention!** *The passed in observer MUST be a ClientHandler! it must know about clients*.

But too much use of marker interface may be sign of bad design too. Which version of these two servers is the right way to do it? what is the right thing to do?

Comment: `It's okay to pass in any object as handler` -- Don't you mean "It's okay to pass in any object that implements `java.util.Observer`?"

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't extend `java.util.Observer` with another interface unless you're actually adding new member definitions to it.

Merely wrapping an interface in another one just to change its name is not enough of a justification, in my opinion.  Your fellow programmers will believe that `ClientHandler` defines additional members, when it fact it does not.  And the purpose of `java.util.Observer` is presumably already well-understood.

Comment: and if I not, wouldn't my colleagues have to go through **all** my code to know what I meant by observer?

Comment: I'm sorry but I haven't worked with really good colleagues to care about these stuff, but seems you have, wouldn't it also ever help with debugging, sharing code, documenting, and more importantly testing? will I be always then looking for and using the most generic type possible? if so, why not just use `object`? why do type checking at all?

Comment: `why not just use object? why do type checking at all?` -- That's called a "slippery slope" logical fallacy.  You use the type that is most appropriate.  That's not necessarily the simplest one.

Comment: `wouldn't my colleagues have to go through all my code to know what I meant by observer?` -- `java.util.Observer` already has a well-known purpose.  If that purpose is the same one as yours, you can use it without confusion.  If your purpose is a different one (i.e. it has different members), then either use a different interface, or create your own.  Implementations having the same interface can still have different behavior; document that behavior in the implementation.

Comment: One final question and you are hero of the day: Can we justify a *Generic Observable* then? like so: [this](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/76924/java-util-observable-but-with-generics-to-avoid-casts) and [this](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/77019/does-java-need-an-observable-object-with-generics). thanks a thousand times.

Comment: @loolooyyyy: The guidance given at the two links you provided already seems more than adequate.